# how can I block the browser xul component from downloading?

Tags: xulrunner

I have a xulrunner app, and I am using the browser object; I would like to call loadURI to download a URL and not have it load any of the content on the page.

Is there a way to specify via pref a way to disable downloading of resources such as CSS, images, JavaScript?

*Update* I found the [nsIDocShell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDocShell) documentation, and this solves half of my problem; is there a way to prevent it from download javascript *and* CSS files?

```
browser.docShell.allowImages = false;
browser.docShell.allowMetaRedirects = false;
browser.docShell.allowAuth = false;
browser.docShell.allowPlugins = false;
browser.docShell.allowSubframes = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [How to stop firefox from downloading and applying CSS via a firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452001/how-to-stop-firefox-from-downloading-and-applying-css-via-a-firefox-extension). It doesn't have an easy answer also, but the questioner does suggest a workaround that might be close enough to your needs.